# (Oracle)Getting 30 days before

Tags: sql, oracle, date, casting

My goal is to get 30 days before.
The data are stored as varchar2 type, '20200630' and '20200613'.
The expected result is '20200531' and '20200514' for each.

I have simply subtracted 30 from my varchar2 '20200630' and '20200613' and 
it shows result by casting, but the result are not expected such as '20200600','20200583' which are not form of date.

Could I know how to modify my code as below

```
WITH A AS
 (SELECT '20200630' YEARMONTHDAY  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '20200613' FROM DUAL)
SELECT YEARMONTHDAY - 30 FROM A;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your data using the appropriate type!  That is, use `date` rather than a string.

If you are stuck with data in this format, convert to date:

```
select to_date(yearmonthday, 'YYYYMMDD') - interval '30' day
```

I would not recommend converting the value back to a string.  Dates should be dates.